# Java module that given two positive integers returns the number of common digits in the same positions

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to java and can't figure out how to solve this simple problem:

> "Make a module that given two positive integers returns the number of common digits in the same positions."

I need to make this Java method without using arrays! How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the digits by using the modulo (`%`) and division (`/`) operators:

```
public static int countCommonDigits(int a, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a > 0 && b >0) {
        // Get the right most digits of each number
        int digitA = a % 10;
        int digitB = b % 10;

        // compare them
        if (digitA == digitB) {
            ++count;
        }

        // move on to the next digit
        a /= 10;
        b /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please don't feed the [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)